# Visiting UK while spouse visa application pending

Tags: visas, uk, spouses, tourism

Is it possible for my wife (a non-visa national) to visit the UK while she has a spouse visa application pending? The application was made from outside the UK, in Spain, where we are both resident.

She has her passport as she paid extra at the Visa Application Centre to keep it.

Comment: Does she have an article 10 card ("tarjeta de residencia de familiar de un ciudadano de la Unión")?  If so she should be able to enter under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations instead of the Immigration Rules (though I don't know whether that makes a difference to the answer of your question).

Comment: VTC: OP has not returned since asking the question, and has not added the clarifying information requested by @phoog.